# Trignometry question for calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I just have a quick question. It's simple but I am  having trouble with it.

> Solve the equation $\:\:12 \cos^2\theta - 6= \sin\theta\:\:$ for $\theta$ in $(-2\pi,2\pi)$.

I am unsure what to do with this except rearrange the terms.

Comment: Let $x=\sin \theta$. Then the equation is $12(1-x^2)-6=x$. Solve this quadratic equation.

Comment: You must re-write $\cos^2\theta$ in terms of $\sin^2\theta$ and then you have a quadratic in form equation in $\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it into a quadratic in terms of $\sin\theta$ and then use the quadratic formula.

\begin{align}
   12\cos^2\theta - 6 &= \sin\theta
 \\12(1-\sin^2\theta) - 6 &= \sin\theta
 \\12-12\sin^2\theta - 6 &= \sin\theta
 \\12\sin^2\theta +\sin\theta - 6 &= 0
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 \implies\quad \theta = \arcsin&\left(\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4(12)(6)}}{2(12)}\right)
 \\\theta = \arcsin\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) \quad&\text{or}\quad \theta = \arcsin\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) 
\end{align}

Comment: Square root of 289 is 17?

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: $\cos^2 \theta = 1 -\sin^2 \theta$

Comment: This isn't just a "hint"; this is the first step.

Answer (score 1):

Deepsea's hint:

$\cos^2 \theta = 1 -\sin^2 \theta$

$$12(1 -\sin^2 \theta)-6=\sin \theta$$

Let $x:=\sin \theta$

$$12-12x^2-6=x\\
12x^2+x-6=0\\
\vdots$$